# Map shows different points depending on what is visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have 90% of what I would like:

https://jsfiddle.net/ruwez7tq/

All I want to do is change the plotted points that are shown depending on which list is visible. At the moment only the first list's ("bars") points can be seen. Even though this is the defualt page load points, when you click on, for example, "Restaurants", The numbered points should update to these locations.

This is the JS I have that plots the points and changes the colour of whatever one is clicked, (when both the point or the list item are clicked):

```
for (i = 0; i < bars.length; i++) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(bars[i][1], bars[i][2]),
        map: map,
        label: String(bars[i][3]),
    });
    gmarkers.push(marker);
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
            infowindow.setContent(bars[i][0]);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
            for (j = 0; j < gmarkers.length; j++) {
                gmarkers[j].setIcon("");
            }
            marker.setIcon("imgs/green.png");
        }
    })(marker, i));
}

$('#bars-list li').each(function(i, e) {
    $(e).click(function(i) {
        return function(e) {
            google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[i], 'click');
        }
    }(i));
});
```

I have 90% of what I would like:

https://jsfiddle.net/ruwez7tq/

All I want to do is change the plotted points that are shown depending on which list is visible. At the moment only the first list's ("bars") points can be seen. Even though this is the defualt page load points, when you click on, for example, "Restaurants", The numbered points should update to these locations.

This is the JS I have that plots the points and changes the colour of whatever one is clicked, (when both the point or the list item are clicked):

I'm trying to work out how to generalise this to each list, and how to utilise it to update the map depending on which list is visible?!

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: In you code when you click on a category you should call a function that  hide  the visible markers and show the markers related .to the category ..

Comment: Are you saying to combine all the 2D arrays into one big array?

Comment: First you must have a on click function on the category div that launch the function .. second ..you have only created the markers for  bars .. instead you should eg: create the markers for all and make visible only the markers related .. to the category selected .. third .. when you select a category you should hide all the markers .. and show only the markers related to the category selected .

Comment: Do you mean like this:

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ruwez7tq/2/

Comment: In the fiddle you have all the markers .. and now you need a function that show only the markers of ine category .. when is selected/clicked

Comment: Thank you for that. Although, I'm unsure on how to construct the function?

Comment: I have posted a brief suggestion  ..

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/80m1psmy/

Comment: @Dr.Molle: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

somethings like this  ( be sure you placed the function and the global vars in window scope  )

for javascript

```
function hide_show( category ){
  for (i = 0; i < amenities.length; i++) {
     gmarkers[i].setMap(null);
      if amenities[3] = category {
        gmarkers[i].setMap(map);
      }
  }
}
```

for html

```
<div id="bars-list" class="lists" onclick"hide_show('bars');">
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I implemented it, but it doesn't appear to work?! :

https://jsfiddle.net/ruwez7tq/10/